# Julia: swap gives errors

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia 0.3.4

I'm trying to write LU-decomposition using Gaussian elimination. So I have to swap rows. And here's my problem:

If I'm using `a,b = b,a` I get an error,

but if I'm using:

```
function swapRows(row1, row2)
    temp = row1
    row1 = row2
    row2 = temp
end
```

then everything works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug?

Here's my source code:

```
function lu_t(A::Matrix)
  # input value: (A), where A is a matrix
  # return value: (L,U), where L,U are matrices

  function swapRows(row1, row2)
    temp = row1
    row1 = row2
    row2 = temp
    return null
  end

  if size(A)[1] != size(A)[2]
    throw(DimException())
  end

  n = size(A)[1] # matrix dimension
  U = copy(A) # upper triangular matrix
  L = eye(n) # lower triangular matrix

  for k = 1:n-1 # direct Gaussian elimination for each column `k`
    (val,id) = findmax(U[k:end,k]) # find max pivot element and it's row `id`

    if val == 0 # check matrix for singularity
      throw(SingularException())
    end

    swapRows(U[k,k:end],U[id,k:end]) # swap row `k` and `id`
    # U[k,k:end],U[id,k:end] = U[id,k:end],U[k,k:end] - error

    for i = k+1:n # for each row `i` > `k`
      μ = U[i,k] / U[k,k] # find elimination coefficient `μ`
      L[i,k] = μ # save to an appropriate position in lower triangular matrix `L`
      for j = k:n # update each value of the row `i`
        U[i,j] = U[i,j] - μ⋅U[k,j]
      end
    end
  end

  return (L,U)
end

###### main code ######
A = rand(4,4)
@time (L,U) = lu_t(A)
@test_approx_eq(L*U, A)
```

Comment: Could the down-voters please leave a comment indicating the reason for the down-vote (there are several posts on meta discussing why this is a good idea). For this question, the reason for down-voting is not obvious to me. I'm voting it back up towards zero.

Answer (score 5):

The `swapRows` function is a no-op and has no effect whatsoever – all it does is swap around some local variable names. See various discussions of the difference between assignment and mutation:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/oSW5hH8vxAo/llAHRvvFVhMJ
- http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#i-passed-an-argument-x-to-a-function-modified-it-inside-that-function-but-on-the-outside-the-variable-x-is-still-unchanged-why
- http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#why-does-x-y-allocate-memory-when-x-and-y-are-arrays

The constant `null` doesn't mean what you think it does – in Julia v0.3 it's a function that computes the null space of a linear transformation; in Julia v0.4 it still means this but has been deprecated and renamed to `nullspace`. The "uninteresting" value in Julia is called `nothing`.

I'm not sure what's wrong with your commented out row swapping code, but this general approach does work:

```
julia> X = rand(3,4)
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.149066  0.706264   0.983477  0.203822
 0.478816  0.0901912  0.810107  0.675179
 0.73195   0.756805   0.345936  0.821917

julia> X[1,:], X[2,:] = X[2,:], X[1,:]
(
1x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.478816  0.0901912  0.810107  0.675179,

1x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.149066  0.706264  0.983477  0.203822)

julia> X
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.478816  0.0901912  0.810107  0.675179
 0.149066  0.706264   0.983477  0.203822
 0.73195   0.756805   0.345936  0.821917
```

Since this creates a pair of temporary arrays that we can't yet eliminate the allocation of, this isn't the most efficient approach. If you want the most efficient code here, looping over the two rows and swapping pairs of scalar values will be faster:

```
function swapRows!(X, i, j)
    for k = 1:size(X,2)
        X[i,k], X[j,k] = X[j,k], X[i,k]
    end
end
```

Note that it is conventional in Julia to name functions that mutate one or more of their arguments with a trailing `!`. Currently, closures (i.e. inner functions) have some performance issues, so you'll want such a helper function to be defined at the top-level scope instead of inside of another function the way you've got it.

Finally, I assume this is an exercise since Julia ships with carefully tuned generic (i.e. it works for arbitrary numeric types) LU decomposition: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/linalg/#Base.lu.

  -

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple

```
julia> A = rand(3,4)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.241426   0.283391  0.201864  0.116797
 0.457109   0.138233  0.346372  0.458742
 0.0940065  0.358259  0.260923  0.578814

julia> A[[1,2],:] = A[[2,1],:]
2×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.457109  0.138233  0.346372  0.458742
 0.241426  0.283391  0.201864  0.116797

julia> A
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.457109   0.138233  0.346372  0.458742
 0.241426   0.283391  0.201864  0.116797
 0.0940065  0.358259  0.260923  0.578814
```